# equivalent of file_get_contents("php://input"); in classic asp

Tags: php, asp-classic

Is this it?

I am trying to convert, `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");` to classic asp...

```
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
    xmlhttp.open "GET", php://input, false 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send
    TOKEN = xmlhttp.responseText
```

edit: Answering John's question...

Realtime Updates

> Following a successful subscription, Facebook will proceed to call
>   your endpoint every time that there are changes (to the chosen fields
>   or connections). For each update, it will make an HTTP POST request.
>
> The request will have content type of application/json and the body
>   will comprise a JSON-encoded string containing one or more changes.
>
> Note for PHP developers: In PHP, to get the encoded data you would use
>   the following code:
>
> $data = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
>   $json = json_decode($data);

Comment: I would refrase this as 'how can I read the raw request body in classic asp'. Nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Yes the code you posted should work. What's wrong with it? What error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit #2

This is an educated guess based on your Facebook info - try

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", Request, false 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.send
TOKEN = xmlhttp.responseText
```

Basically this is your original idea with a little change in line 2 and another in line 3.  You could also try Request.Form rather than Request in line 2 as the script is receiving POST data

Edit - yes, it looks like your code will work, with one minor change.  Your URL needs to go inside double quotes - ie

```
xmlhttp.open "GET", "php://input", false
```

Thanks for the question.  I've learned something today.  I'll leave my original answer as background reading

Could you tell me a bit more about what you are trying to achieve.  It looks like you want to take the content of an external URL and then use it in your ASP page.  You can certainly use an XML object provided that the output of your external URL is valid XML.  The code looks like this.

```
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.load("http://yoururl")
```

You then have an xml object, here just called "xml" which you can use however you need.  For example if you just want it to appear in the page as is you would add

```
Response.write xml
```

If your external URL output is not valid XML then I don't think Classic ASP can't do this on its own, you may need to install a third party component on your server, such as AspTear

http://www.alphasierrapapa.com/ComponentCenter/AspTear/

The code you suggest above, or a variation on it, might well work, I'm going to experiment with it.  Classic ASP itself has had no updates for more than a decade but Microsoft's XML processor certainly has been updated

Comment: John, thanks a lot for your research and message. Facebook is sending me HTTP POST request that has JSON-encoded string and I want to get that data inserted in the database.

Comment: Also, I managed to count the string with `tot_bytes = Request.TotalBytes`. So I can get the it in a binary format but I couldnt find a way to convert it into a string.

Comment: OK, in your example you've created an object called "TOKEN" which corresponds to "$data".  You'll need to write your own json_decode function, (or google for one someone else has written)

Comment: The usual way to convert to a string in Classic ASP is Cstr(yourobjectname)

Comment: John, problem is my example is not correct. I am not requesting data from Facebook. It posts me the data when one of my users update their information.

Comment: That didnt work either. `tot_bytes = Request.TotalBytes` returns 124. I guess thats the number of characters in the message that I get from Facebook. I need to find a way to convert that incoming data to string

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas I'm afraid.  PHP works fine on IIS.  If all else fails you could always have a callback page in PHP alongside the rest of the site in ASP - it looks like there's a lot more documentation for a PHP solution

Comment: John, turns out ADODB.Stream is the solution. Thank you so much for all your help.