# How to send Json object (or string data) from xmlhttprequest using Classic ASP?

Tags: json, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I wrote an ASP Script to generate JSON data/string.  How do i send that data to a web service?  I was given the info below, and i do not have access to the server to register any dll files. I did some searching and saw that i should be using XMLHttpRequest but not sure how to do that.

Please help. Thank you.

Connecting to the web service
The web service works over the HTTP protocol. It is recommended that this web service, once in production, use a Secure Socket Layer (HTTPS). The web service is designed to work with the URL: http://thedomain.com/api/push

The site uses an authentication token in the header to prevent crawlers from interfering with the web service. When sending data add a header called HTTP_TOKENKEY with the value of ABCDEFGHIJKL. This is one reason why HTTPS is recommended.
The web service will look for JSON data in the request’s POST and sends JSON responses back to the client.

This is what i have so far

---

```
strJSONToSend = theevent 

webserviceurl = "http://thedomain.com/api/push"

Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") 
objRequest.open "POST", webserviceurl, False 

objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "HTTP_TOKENKEY","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceurl

results = objRequest.send (strJSONToSend)
write (results)

set objJSONDoc = nothing 
set objResult = nothing
```

---

this freezes up and does nothing

Comment: Are there any clues in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440378/equivalent-of-file-get-contentsphp-input-in-classic-asp/15451764#15451764

Comment: none that i have available to me :(

Comment: you should use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP instead of xmlhttp because xmlhttp uses WinInet which is not supported on serverside

Comment: Have you watched the http request in Fiddler?  Sometimes you can capture information about what is going on with the request.

Comment: @nkman Did you find a solution, if so could you post as an answer so this doesn't appear as an unanswered question? See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I published before at this URL adapted for your situation:

http://naterice.com/articles/69

```
strJSONToSend = theevent 
webserviceurl = "http://thedomain.com/api/push"

sResponseHTML = GetHTTP(strJSONToSend, webserviceurl)
If len(HTTPErrorHandeler) > 0 Then
  strResponse = HTTPErrorHandeler
Else
  strResponse = sResponseHTML
End If

Response.Write strResponse

Function GetHTTP(sSendHTML, sURL)
  'This script is provided under the Creative Commons license located'
  'at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/ . It may not'
  'be used for commercial purposes with out the expressed written consent'
  'of NateRice.com'
  Set oHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  oHTTP.Open "POST", sURL, false
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader "HTTP_TOKENKEY","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ" 
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceurl

  On Error Resume Next
  oHTTP.send sSendHTML
  sHTTPResponse = oHTTP.responseText

  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    GetHTTP = sHTTPResponse
  Else
    GetHTTP = HTTPErrorHandeler
  End If
  On Error Goto 0

  Set oHTTP = Nothing
End Function


Function HTTPErrorHandeler
  'This script is provided under the Creative Commons license located'
  'at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/ . It may not'
  'be used for commercial purposes with out the expressed written consent'
  'of NateRice.com'
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  HTTPErrorHandeler = "ERROR <br />" & _
             "  ERR Number: " & Err.Number & " <br />" & _
             "  ERR Description: " & Err.Description
  Else
  HTTPErrorHandeler = ""
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that 6 years later, this is still a great write up and made it super easy for me to use and change to fit my needs.